# Error trying to connect to panda

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following panda guide to integrate a rails app to panda for embedding a video in my app.

I have setup the panda.yml as follows:

```
development:
   access_key: 805264cac2c2cbf61e69
   secret_key: 133aa3bbf1d8cdf56f13
   cloud_id: cloudbear
```

My panda.rb initializer file has the following (I do not want to host this app in heroku):

```
   Panda.configure((ENV['PANDASTREAM_URL'] ||
   YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"..",
  "panda.yml"))[Rails.env]))
```

My gemfile:

```
   gem 'panda', '~> 1.5.0'
```

When I try to fire up the rails console I get:

```
  /home/vasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/panda-1.5.0/lib/panda/panda.rb:12:in 
 `configure': missing auth params or block (ArgumentError)
```

A look at the configure method inside the panda module shows that it expects either auth_params or block.

What do I seem to be missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When i put in the cloud id (instead of its name as I had done above), I am able to fire up the rails console and connect to panda. cheers!